# How to use the same instance of page object in multiple tests

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

I would like to know different ways of how to use the same instance of page object in multiple tests that are in same class as well as in different classes.

For ex:
Application that i'm testing hs Home Page, Home page has links to Add Employee, Modify Employee, Employee Details, and Company Details.. pages

In my implementation, 
Page class - contains common functions that are performed on the pages

HomePage class- Has the functions to interact with the HomePage

AddEmployeePage class- Has the functions to interact with the AddEmployeePage

ModifyEmployeePage class- Has the functions to interact with the ModifyEmployeePage

EmployeeDetailsPage class- Has the functions to interact with the EmployeeDetailsPage

CompanyDetailsPage class- Has the functions to interact with the CompanyDetailsPage

All the following tests classes extends Page class.

HomePageTest class- has all the tests for the Home Page

AddEmployeeTest class- has all the tests for the Add EmployeePage

ModifyEmployeeTest class- has all the tests for the Modify EmployeePage

EmployeeDetailsTest class- has all the tests for the Employee Details Page

CompanyDetailsTest class- has all the tests for the Company Details Page

For all the tests related to the HomePage and other pages, I want to use the HomePage object that I create for the first time.

To achieve this, currently I'm declaring all the page objects as static in the Page class and then referring to the same object in the test.

Is this the right way to do? Will it have any impact when I run the tests in multiple browsers? or run tests parallely?  Please let me know

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You should also consider the PageFactory and CacheLookup concept as well. - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems good. Its better to have common business login/ Functions in single class for example in your case you have AddEmployeePage for wich you can have functions like Adding a Employee, Editing and deleting etc.. This is good approach since you don't have to go to each and every tests classes for a minor change in your business login or Page source changes/addition of new fields etc.. By changing a single function like adding user all the tests classes will have the same login updated for adding a user. I will suggest instead of extending the classes use static member functions and variable in common classes. it will be than easier to handle and update and static members can be called anywhere in other test classes by just classname.
We have implemented the similar login in our project and its works well with all browsers like IE,FF and chrome. As far as paraller testing is considered just make sure you don't run two test classes in parallel which can impact other test class running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that using static methods will yield in any number of problems soon enough. Specially when declaring your shared resources as static (like webdriver itself). There are several times i have tried writing my webdriver projects as static and every time I have finished rewriting it all. Last time it was in august, look at me struggeling with this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510854/junit-testwatcher-failed-and-finished-methods-firing-time).

Better consider writing you page objects as instances and create nested page objects. Something like, let say that your home page has button "go to add employee" and after clicking addempolyeepage is returned.

```
class HomePage extends LoadableComponent<HomePage>{

    public HomePage(){
        // Construcotr
    }

    @FindBy(id = "buttonAddEmployee")
    private WebElement btnAddEmp;

    @Override
    protected void load() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void isLoaded() throws Error {

    }

    public AddEmployeePage goToAddEmployeePage(){
        btnAddEmp.click();
        return new AddEmployeePage();
}
}

class AddEmployeePage{
    public void addEmployee(){
        // Add 
    }
}

class Test{
     @org.junit.Test
    public void testStuff(){
         new HomePage()
                 .goToAddEmployeePage()
                 .addEmployee();
     }
}
```